# How to dispose a WPF application GUI?

Tags: c#

I have a WPF application with a GUI on the MainWindow. I want to dispose this window after a while based on some user actions. But I want the application continue to run in background. I know that Window can be set to hidden, but it still uses the memory.How to destroy the MainWindow without quitting the WPF application? Also I would like to know if it is possible to relaunch the  MainWindow after it was disposed.

Comment: Not familiar with WPF, but wouldn't it be simpler to put the background task in a console app and have the console app control the appearance/disappareance/dispose/etc of any UI you need?

Comment: Is it possible to launch a WPF window from a console app?

Comment: I don't know about a window itself, but you could launch a WPF app from the console to handle the GUI.

Comment: That sounds like a good suggestion. I have to get to know more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.Close(); //Will close the window but keep the application running.

var mw = new MainWindow();
mw.Show(); //Will open a new MainWindow and show it.
mw.Close(); //Close this one too.
```

That said hiding it is the best choice, the amount of memory it uses should really be irrelevant. That's what memory is there for.

Comment: So this.close() will free the memory used for MainWindow?

Comment: Okay. But My GUI is a little heavy. I think close would be better.